# Is there a way to get the information about cancelled query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

In our snowflake, we have multiple users accessing the database. And sometimes when query takes long time people are cancelling the query from UI.
I was wondering if there is a way to get information about who has cancelled the query.
Like we have table QUERY_HISTORY to get information about the query.

Do we have a similar table to get information of query cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

Only the user who executed the query can cancel it via the `Abort` button in the UI.  Other ways to cancel a query would be to issue one of the following functions:

- SYSTEM$CANCEL_QUERY
- SYSTEM$CANCEL_ALL_QUERIES
- SYSTEM$ABORT_SESSION
- SYSTEM$ABORT_TRANSACTION
- ALTER WAREHOUSE ... ABORT ALL QUERIES
- ALTER USER ... ABORT ALL QUERIES

Any one of the above functions that are issued would be a query in the QUERY_HISTORY as well.

A cancelled query will have an error of 604, and I expect that the error code is different if the query has timed out (which by default is set to 2 days).

Comment: Check the last query that I had time out and the code was 630.

Answer (score 0):

The question is whether there is a table that stores cancelled queries like QUERY_HISTORY, I think.  The answer is that even a cancelled query will be in QUERY_HISTORY.